# Create env fails when using a daemonset to create processes in Kubernetes

Tags: process, set, kubernetes, daemon

I want to deploy a software in to nodes with daemonset, but it is not a docker app. I created a daemonset json like this :

```
"template": {
      "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": null,
        "labels": {
          "app": "uniagent"
        },
        "annotations": {
          "scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerations": "[{\"key\":\"beta.k8s.io/accepted-app\",\"operator\":\"Exists\", \"effect\":\"NoSchedule\"}]"
        },
        "enable": true
      },
      "spec": {
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
        "securityContext": {},
        "processes": [
          {
            "name": "foundation",
            "package": "xxxxx",
            "resources": {
              "limits": {
                "cpu": "100m",
                "memory": "1Gi"
              }
            },
            "lifecyclePlan": {
              "kind": "ProcessLifecycle",
              "namespace": "engb",
              "name": "app-plc"
            },
           "env": [
            {
              "name": "SECRET_USERNAME",
              "valueFrom": {
                "secretKeyRef": {
                  "name": "key-secret",
                  "key": "uniagentuser"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "SECRET_PASSWORD",
              "valueFrom": {
                "secretKeyRef": {
                  "name": "key-secret",
                  "key": "uniagenthash"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
          },
```

when the app deploy succeeds, the env variables do not exist at all.

What should I do to solve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Daemon Sets have to be docker containers. You can't have non-containerized programs run as Daemon Sets. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/ Kubernetes only launches containers.

Also in your YAML manifest file, I see a `"processes"` key and I have reason to believe it's not a valid manifest file, so I doubt you deployed it successfully.

You have not pasted the "full" YAML file, but I'm guessing the "template" key at the beginning is the spec.template key of the file.

Run `kubectl explain daemonset.spec.template.spec` and you'll see that there is no `"processes"` field.